# How to get all children in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After adding the values to database of firebase like that:

```
writeNewUser("0",name , "0", "1" );
 writeNewUser("1",name , "0", "2" );
 writeNewUser("2",name , "0", "3" );
 writeNewUser("3",name , "0", "4" );

private void writeNewUser(String GameID, String name, String wpm , String userID) {
        User user = new User(name, wpm , userID );

        mDatabase.child("games").child(GameID).setValue(user);
    }

    @IgnoreExtraProperties
    public class User {

        public String name;
        public String wpm;
        public String userID;

        public User() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
        }

        public User(String name, String wpm , String userID) {
            this.name = name;
            this.wpm = wpm;
            this.userID = userID;
        }

    }
```

And example of how it looks like in firebase:
Games > 0 > Name: , WPM: , ID:
Games > 1 > Name: , WPM: , ID:

What i want to receive is the from the database are the GameID's sorted from low to high

I would be glad to get some help since I'm new to this database and been searching for few hours already.

Comment: Can you post your data getting code?

Comment: @MohammadAldefrawy I was trying to use getChildren() but i couldn't understand how is this working and which var should i use it on

Comment: Do you just want the data once initially or do you want realtime updates from the database i.e an update every time the "games" database gets modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to get all the games in the database ordered by key(GameID) assuming you don't need realtime updates.

```
    final HashMap<Long,User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("games").orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> snapshotIterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot aSnapshotIterable : snapshotIterable) {
                userMap.put(Long.parseLong(aSnapshotIterable.getKey()),aSnapshotIterable.getValue(User.class));
            }
          Set<Long> gameIds = userMap.keySet();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you , Where can i read about the realtime updates and see the difference between them?

Comment: You can read about the difference here.https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: You will not be able to get the exact changes if that's what you mean by "difference". I'd be able to help you better if you can help me understand the use-case  better.

Comment: I've tried to code , but it says there is error: "Class com.example.dimon.typeracer.OnlineActivity$User is missing a constructor with no arguments" in this line: userArrayList.add(aSnapshotIterable.getValue(User.class));

Comment: Make the user class static or create a separate file for the User class.

Comment: Its works now , but why is the result i'm receiving is 

USERS NUMBER:: com.example.dimon.typeracer.User@e3bad94
D/USERS NUMBER:: com.example.dimon.typeracer.User@2c4303d
D/USERS NUMBER:: com.example.dimon.typeracer.User@695032

And not 0 , 1 2

Comment: Updated the code to receive both keys and values. The "userMap" object contains the mapping from "GameId"s to "User" objects and the "gameIds" object contains the list of GameIds i.e 0,1,2.